# PHP reformat the output display in the below code

Tags: php

How reformat the output display in the below code

```
$columns =2;//No of column
$dataToDisplay = array('green', 'blue', 'white', 'apple', 'computers', 'php');
echo "<table width='100%'>";
$columnwidth = 100/$columns;
$count = count($dataToDisplay);
$i =0;
foreach($dataToDisplay as $data) {
    if($i % $columns == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . $data . "</td>";
    if(($i % $columns) == ($columns - 1) || ($i + 1) == $num_rows){
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

> ```
> green | blue
> white | apple
> computers | php
> ```

But how to convert the above snippet like below sample output

> ```
> green | STATIC SIGNUP FORM WILL COME HERE
> blue | white
> apple| computers
> php
> ```

DIV instead table output format

Comment: my input which i tried is array_splice( $dataToDisplay, 1, 0, array('sttic form') );  i would like to know, is there any better option other than this ?

Comment: Is `$dataToDisplay` fixed? Because the way the array is structured it's not suited for display like that.